# Having trouble to assign a value from an enum in a switch loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

In my model, I have this enum that looks like this:

```
public enum m_ItemType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    //
    Physical = 1,
    //
    Logical = 2,
}
```

And I have this method which builds a list of items based on another list of item which has this enum value:

```
private static List<ItemType> BuildListItem(IEnumerable<ItemToSend> listItemToSend)
{
     List<ItemType> listItemsToReturn = new List<ItemType>();

     foreach (var item in listItemToSend)
     {
          ItemType itemToAdd = new ItemType();

          itemToAdd.Title = item.m_Title;
          itemToAdd.Description = item.m_Description;

          switch (item.m_ItemType)
          {
              case 0:
                 itemToAdd.Type = AnotherEnumValue.Unknown;
                 break;
              case 1:
                 itemToAdd.Type = AnotherEnumValue.Physical;
                 break;
              case 2:
                 itemToAdd.Type = AnotherEnumValue.Logical;
                 break;
          }    

          listItemsToReturn.Add(itemToAdd);
     }

     return listItemsToReturn;
}
```

But the code does not compile and keep telling me that the enum name is not valid at this point. Can anyone explain me why? I don't get it.

Comment: Could you specify the exact error message emitted by the compiler?

Comment: what is the data type of `itemToAdd.Type`?

Comment: Couple of things. Would help to see your `ItemType` and `ItemToSend` models, and also, Type is a reserved keyword so you probably don't want to be using that as a property name

Comment: @Steve "cannot reference a type through an expression;"

Comment: @Sachin oh, err, I thought that an enum returned an int based on the value assigned, so if the value is Type.Unknown, its value would be 0?

Comment: @musefan I would like to show you ItemType, but I cannot since it is a compiled code and would give away the type of app I'm building, which I can't.
But I'll answer your questions: Type is an enum contained in the ItemType.

Comment: @HerveS if `itemToAdd.Type` have `int` datatype then you need  cast it to int like `itemToAdd.Type = (int)AnotherEnumValue.Unknown;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data type of `item.m_ItemType` is `m_ItemType`, first I would rename that to something a bit more sensible (`ItemType` should work). Then you need to use that name in the case statements of your switch. Try this:

```
// your enum
public enum ItemType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    //
    Physical = 1,
    //
    Logical = 2,
}

// your model
public class ItemToSend
{
    public ItemType m_ItemType { get; set; }
}

// in your action
private static List<ItemType> BuildListItem(IEnumerable<ItemToSend> listItemToSend)
{
    ...
    switch (item.m_ItemType)
    {
        case ItemType.Unknown:
            itemToAdd.Type = AnotherEnumValue.Unknown;
            break;
        case ItemType.Physical:
            itemToAdd.Type = AnotherEnumValue.Physical;
            break;
        case ItemType.Logical:
            itemToAdd.Type = AnotherEnumValue.Logical;
            break;
    } 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Although this "could" work, the first error remains. Is it because I try to use an enum value? Should I use an int instead?

Comment: I'd have to see more of the code to know for sure what's going on. what's the data type of `item.m_ItemType` and `itemToAdd.Type`? Also, do you *intend* to have two virtually identical enums (`m_ItemType` and `AnotherEnumValue`)?

Comment: I must admit that I am really not used to manipulate enums, so maybe that's why it seems illogical.
in my itemToAdd, there's an enum. I thought that I needed to use an enum to have nearly identical values, so that's why I built an enum on the other side...

Comment: That's fine, but it could lead to some confusion, so you should exercise a little caution. See my updated answer.

Comment: Aaah! thank you! Now I understand: I have made a "get / set" property based on the enum value like you suggested in the class and it works.
But I frankly admit that this may lead to confusion, so I will refactor the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example the enum is named `m_ItemType`, but should rather be `AnotherEnumValue`.

Therefore, in the line `switch (item.m_ItemType)` the value after the dot is interpreted as a type name, not a field.

Comment: I cannot do that since the compiler says "Value of integral type expected". I though that an enum would always return an integer value?

Comment: Please use different names for the `enum` itself and the field that contains a value of that enum. This would clarify the situation a lot.